# Threshold for connectivity in random bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, random-graphs

I need to find the threshold probability for the increasing property of being connected in a random bipartite graph $G(n,n,p(n))$ in the Erdos-Renyi model where every edge appears with probability $p(n)$ independently. Any ideas or a references where to start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you may know, connectivity in $G(n,p)$ hinges upon whether there are isolated vertices or not. At this threshold of disappearance of isolated vertices, you can use a first moment argument to deal with components with at least 2 vertices. What happens when you do a similar argument for $G(n, n, p)$?

Comment: Yeah but the graph with no isolated vertices doesn't mean the graph is connected so i also must show there are not connected components of size between $2$ and $n$ in $G(n,n,p)$?

Comment: Correct. Try to bound the probability that there is a component with $a$+$b$ vertices where $a$ is the number of left vertices and $b$ is the number of right vertices. Try to follow the argument for $G(n,p)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will post any advance!